# Get Linux screen application output onto a PHP site on Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, linux, terminal, output

I want to display the output of a screen session (the application called "Screen") on to a website im making. To begin with i only want to be able to display the output, and not send any input. Im thinking i can do this and then regularly update the containing div with some Ajax calls, but unsure where to begin.

Does Screen store its output in a file that i could read with PHP and then display? And if so, wheres that file located?

Other suggestions?

Just keep in mind it has to be lightweight, as it is running on a Raspberry Pi

Comment: screen's output isn't just the text output from whatever programs you're running inside the screen session. it's also terminal control sequences that accomplish the blanking/switching when you switch between screen "windows". web browsers would have no idea what those terminal control sequences are, and display them as plain characters. however, since screen attaches to a terminal, you could just read from the terminal file.

Comment: Can you pipe the output of your command into a file? If yes, you can get your webserver to stream the contents of that file.

Comment: I just found out that the program i was starting inside the screen session, already did save its output to a file. which i can then just read with php and output.